# Multi undefined variables from a form and subsequent sql statement

Tags: php, sql

The outcome I seek is to loop through items taken from a form that isset or true and then have a sql statement query the database. The complication comes from I have 9 fields that the user could choose one or more or all fields (It is a search database but every time you choose an extra field it refines the search). The part of the code to return true I can get my head around by using a foreach loop but how would you link it to SQL query if the outcome is varied?

Answer (score 1):

You generate a different query depending on which fields are entered.
Luckily this isn't too hard in SQL: all those fields are in the `WHERE` clause:

```
$where = [ 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 0 ];
$sth = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE " .
    implode( " AND ",
        array_map( function($i) { return "$i=?"; }, array_keys( $where ) ) )
    );
$sth->execute( array_values( $where ) );
```

Of course, if there are relationships between the fields, the query may become more complicated, but this is the gist of it.

Answer (score -1):

Learning this takes time and patience I have cut past the variables from the form

```
    if(isset($_POST['Search'])){
    $packID = $_POST['packID'];
    $supplier_name = $_POST['supplier_name'];
    $timber_species = $_POST['timber_species'];
    $timber_product = $_POST['timber_product'];
    $timber_grade = $_POST['timber_grade'];
    $timber_finish = $_POST['timber_finish'];
    $timber_treatment = $_POST['timber_treatment'];
    $width = $_POST['width'];
    $thickness = $_POST['thickness'];
    $length = $_POST['length'];
    $markup = $_POST['markup'];
} else{

    $packID="";
    $supplier_name="";
    $timber_species="";
    $timber_product="";
    $timber_grade="";
    $timber_finish="";
    $timber_treatment="";
    $width= "";
    $thickness= "";
    $length="";

}
```

How would you write this Kenney when the variables may or may not be set. I must admit I am a novice and keen to learn. It takes time and patience.